# Typecasting in C, big issue

Tags: c, casting, binary-data

I am currently at a standstill on how to proceed with correctly type casting information.

I am given a buffer of binary data, accessed from a `char*`, and need to pull out all the information it stores. I know I should be typecasting, but I am doing something wrong!

Functions like `atoi`, `atol`, `atof` do not work because it is not a string of numbers, but more like a string of `0`s and `1`s that need to be interpreted as numbers.

In a broad sense, you can think of it as the following format `char` `long int` `char` `unsigned int` `double`, Now, if I were to want this first line, I am doing something like:

```
char temp_c1 = (char)*(buffer);
long int temp_i = (long int)*(buffer+1);
char temp_c2 = (char)*(buffer+5);
unsigned int temp_ui = (unsigned int)*(buffer+6);
double temp_d = (double)*(buffer+10);
```

My values for `long int`, `unsigned int`, and `double` are all incorrect, but both `char`s are correct. I do not understand how to correctly typecast a string of binary data to the types `long int`, `unsigned int`, and `double`. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You don't type cast from a string value to a number in C - you have to use conversion functions (or write your own).  You need to look at string parsing.  Type casting does not convert the binary data in any way - only your view of it.

Comment: how exactly does the input string look like ? you said 0's and 1's, is it a string like '00110101'  or is it a binary file you read.

Comment: If you could dump the first line of your data in hex, along with that would you expected to get for temp_i and temp_d, that would cut out the guessing and get you the right help quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
long int temp_i = (long int)*(buffer+1);
```

(and others), you are likely invoking undefined behavior due to dereferencing pointers to unaligned data, which can manifest itself in "incorrect" (<sic; unexpected) results.

Comment: Fixed the dereferencing fixed the issue, should be
'long int temp_i = *(long int*)(buffer+1);'

Comment: This code is highly defined. Casting a `char` to a `long int` is fine. As Jens points out, you need to cast to `long int *` before dereferencing to invoke funky behavior

Comment: Hm misread that as `*(long int *)(buffer + 1)`, because frankly, `long i = (long)*buffer[1]` does not make too much sense (the cast is redundant in this case).

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely a [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue.

The integer 0x00001034 could be stored in little- or big-endian as follows:

- `{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x34 }`
- `{ 0x34, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 }`

I suggest reading this article:

- [Writing endian-independent code in C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-)

Also, you shouldn't assume that a `long int` or an `unsigned int` is exactly 4 bytes. It depends on your computer's architecture and the compiler.

Comment: The OP mentions a string of `0`s and `1`s - so I think the issue is more general than that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that you just get the derefferencing wrong. Something like

```
long int temp_i = (long int)*(buffer+1);
```

first dereferences a `char*` and optains a `char`, say `'a'`, which for C is just a (small) number. You then cast this to a `long int`.

What you perhaps meant is

```
long int temp_i = *(long int*)(buffer+1);
```

which first re-inteprets the `char*` to be a pointer to `long int`, then derefferences this to read it as as number of the correct width.

But as jørgensen indicates, be careful with alignment. Not all types are allowed to start at whatever byte address.

Comment: This would be the issue. I needed to cast it as a pointer to said variable type before dereferencing it. Thanks :)